# added model to gazebo models database cannot be lauched from world file or inserted from the insert model interface on the GUI?

Tags: gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello ,

I was trying to follow the simple gripper tutorial http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/build_robot/simple_gripper

by creating a folder that contains my .sdf  model and the .config file and adding it to ~/.gazebo/models .

And then I created the world file as following to launch my model from it :

```
  <sdf version="1.4">
    <world name="default">
```

```
  <include>
        <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>

  </include>

  <include>
     <uri>model://sun</uri>
  </include>

  <include>
     <uri>model://apartment_floor0</uri>
  </include>

    </world>
  </sdf>
```

the problem is when I start gazebo with this world file , only ground plane and sun models show up. And then I tried another way to launch the model by running gazebo and  importing the model through the insert model interface on the GUI but the model is not there.

I also added the uri file of the model in the database.config file in the ~/.gazebo/models directory.
Can anyone please tell me what am I missing or what could be went wrong ? Because I believe I have followed the instructions on the simple gripper tutorial pretty much well.
thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2975/added-model-to-gazebo-models-database-cannot-be-lauched-from-world-file-or-inserted-from-the-insert-model-interface-on-the-gui-??/) by [Zahra](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/320/zahra/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 122 on 2013-05-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-05-24**:
Could you post your .config file, or double check that the names corespond to the model you are trying to insert? What error message do you get when you try to insert it from the .world file? And do you add it in its own folder, as in ~/.gazebo/models/yourmodel/ ? Cheers

**Comment by [Zahra](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/320/zahra/) on 2013-05-24**:
here is the model.config file :

apartment_floor0 1.0 apartment_floor0.sdf Zahraame@my.email  
empty apartment floor0. 
I dont get any error messages except this warning  that I got after I hav added the uri file in the database.config file that is existed in ~/.gazebo/models directoryInvalid filename or directory.

**Comment by [Zahra](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/320/zahra/) on 2013-05-24**:
Invalid filename or directory["/home/shahed.gazebo/models/database.config~"] in GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH. It's not a good idea to put extra files in a GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH because the file structure may be modified by Gazebo.
I created a folder in ~/.gazebo /models directory called apartment_floor0 , in this folder there's the model.config file which I posted, and the apartment_floor0.sdf model.

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-05-24**:
you could try not adding the model to the database.config file, I usually don't add them there, and it works for me

**Comment by [Zahra](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/320/zahra/) on 2013-05-25**:
Thanks a lot , you are right about the tags. It works good now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It looks like there's an error in your model.config file. You have mismatched tags: apartmentfloor0.sdf

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0